# Issue with imsdroid integration with my android application

Tags: android

We have problem related with Imsdroid Integration with my android application.During the application startup it gives error as follow..
**ExceptionInInitializerError**

**My log file is:**

```
07-19 19:55:58.047: E/AndroidRuntime(6858): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-19 19:55:58.047: E/AndroidRuntime(6858): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
07-19 19:55:58.047: E/AndroidRuntime(6858):     at org.doubango.imsdroid.MyMainClass.<init>(MyMainClass.java:43)
07-19 19:55:58.047: E/AndroidRuntime(6858):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
07-19 19:55:58.047: E/AndroidRuntime(6858):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
07-19 19:55:58.047: E/AndroidRuntime(6858):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1053)
07-19 19:55:58.047: E/AndroidRuntime(6858):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2099)
07-19 19:55:58.047: E/AndroidRuntime(6858):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
07-19 19:55:58.047: E/AndroidRuntime(6858):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:149)
07-19 19:55:58.047: E/AndroidRuntime(6858):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1300)
07-19 19:55:58.047: E/AndroidRuntime(6858):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-19 19:55:58.047: E/AndroidRuntime(6858):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
07-19 19:55:58.047: E/AndroidRuntime(6858):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4987)
07-19 19:55:58.047: E/AndroidRuntime(6858):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-19 19:55:58.047: E/AndroidRuntime(6858):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-19 19:55:58.047: E/AndroidRuntime(6858):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:821)
07-19 19:55:58.047: E/AndroidRuntime(6858):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
07-19 19:55:58.047: E/AndroidRuntime(6858):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-19 19:55:58.047: E/AndroidRuntime(6858): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-19 19:55:58.047: E/AndroidRuntime(6858):     at org.doubango.ngn.NgnEngine.<clinit>(NgnEngine.java:75)
07-19 19:55:58.047: E/AndroidRuntime(6858):     ... 16 more
```

Answer (score 0):

I think its with your AndroidManifest. Try putting this on your Application tag

```
android:name="org.doubango.ngn.NgnApplication"
```

or

if you have a custom Application object extend NgnApplication object instead of Application object.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use imsdroid in your application then you need to use ChromeView instead of WebView in android xml file.
I found more information and at [here](http://geekonjava.blogspot.in/2014/08/chromium-webview-custom-android-webview.html)

```
<us.costan.chrome.ChromeView
android:id="@+id/customWebView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
/>
```